# Human realistic AI for game bots

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, game-ai

What strategys exist for creating ai game bots that play like humans?

Could someone guide me where to find more information on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

[open ai](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-an-ai-game-bot-using-openai-gym-and-universe-f2eb9bfbb40a), and [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-an-ai-game-bot-using-openai-gym-and-universe-f2eb9bfbb40a) tutorial seams beginners friendly.